# Plot onto a pdf canvas

Tags: pdf, androidplot

My app uses AndroidPlot to generate charts based on data users entered, users can also create PDF files from that data to share. Now, I'd like these PDF documents to not only show the raw data but also the charts they get inside the app.

Is there a way with AndroidPlot to directly draw to a PDF canvas or maybe create a bitmap in the background which gets drawn on the pdf?
Thanks